# Can `from_unixtime` slow this query down?

Tags: mysql

I have been tasked to optimize the following query.

```
select
c.account_key,
c.cohort,
date(concat(year(from_unixtime(min(f.processdate_est_key))), '-', 
month(from_unixtime(min(f.processdate_est_key))), '-1')) as 
customer_conversion_month
from
bidw_stage.cohort c left join
bidw.fact f
on
c.account_key = f.account_key and
f.usage_dollars != 0 and
12 * (year(from_unixtime(f.processdate_est_key)) - year(c.cohort)) + 
 (month(from_unixtime(f.processdate_est_key)) - month(c.cohort)) >= 2
group by c.account_key, c.cohort;
```

It took 30 seconds to complete last January. It now takes almost 3 minutes. The fact table contains about 30 million records, the cohort table about 20k. Fact table attribute  'account_key' is indexed but it is not on the 'cohort' table.

I didn't write this query and the original coder left no documentation as to the reason for this

```
12 * (year(from_unixtime(f.processdate_est_key)) - year(c.cohort)) + 
   (month(from_unixtime(f.processdate_est_key)) - month(c.cohort))
```

Could this be slowing the query down? How can this be optimized?

Comment: If you use a function on a column then the index can never be used. Indexes only apply to raw (unmanipulated) column data

Comment: Anything with a `WHERE` on a computed column usually requires a table scan, so performance is going to be brutal. If you can switch these columns to native `DATETIME` format you're half way there. You may want to use [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) on those values instead of this formula.

Comment: FYI, what that condition is checking is if `processdate_est_key` is in at least the 2nd month after `cohort`. So if `cohort` is in Feb 2017, it will be true for any `processdate_est_key` in Apr 2017 or later.

Comment: Is `processdate_est_key` indexed? If neither `f.processdate_est_key` nor `c.cohort` are indexed, you're going to have to do a full scan either way.

Comment: @Barmar `cohort` is not indexed but `processdate_est_key` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes don't help if you call a function on the column that's indexed. You need to write a condition that compares the unmodified value of an indexed column to something.

The condition your query is testing for is `processdate_est_key` is in at least the 2nd month after `cohort`. Instead of converting this column to a date and extracting the year and month from that, we need to generate a unix timstamp for the beginning of that month and compare with that.

```
AND f.processdate_est_key >= 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(YEAR(c.cohort + INTERVAL 2 MONTH),
                              MONTH(c.cohort + INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '01'))
```

The concatenation gets the date 2 months after `c.cohort`, extracts that year and month, appends `01` to refer to the first day of that month. Then it calls `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to convert that to numeric form for comparing with `f.processdate_est_key`.

Comment: that makes sense! Thank you. Too bad I cannot vote you up (not enough rep points).